# Re-compile config file for WPF application?

Tags: wpf, config

After build my solution (WPF application), the config file is created in project\bin\debug folder. Whenever a change is made to this config file, I have to re-compile/rebuild the project to pull the changes from the config file.

Is there a way to avoid re-compiling the project after making a change in config?
This somehow throws the whole purpose of config file.

Answer (score 0):

If you talk about the App.config file (an XML file where you usually put appSettings, connectionStrings, etc): it is possible to modify this one without to recompile your project / solution. Just navigate to the project\bin\debug folder, there you'll find a file that is called {AssemblyName}.exe.config which you can edit (actually, this is a renamed version of the App.config file, this happens when the build process copies it to the output directory).

If you talk about XAML related files: these are by default not configurable because they get translated to BAML (Binary Application Markup Language) files that are embedded to the assembly in a default WPF project. If you change those you have to recompile.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to recompile your project. Your assumption is wrong.

if you edit OutputDir\{appname}.exe.config, then it will take effect immediatelly. However, if you rebuild your app, this config file is overwritten by app.config from your project folder